# Using phonegap build for Phonegap 3.1 does not call call onDeviceReady

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0, cordova-3

Phonegap 3.1 with jquery mobile. Works fine locally. This is the first part of my code. The alert does not get called.  Any hints? Thank you.

```
enter code here
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>XX</title>
<meta name="description" content=" " />
<meta name="keywords" content=" " />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="css/jqm-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link type="text/css" href="css/mobile.simpledialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqm-datebox.mode.durationbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqm-datebox.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/datebox.i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() 
    {           
      alert("here");
```

Comment: Might be js problem remove other extra js temporary and test

Comment: I don't think it's a js error because the rest of the js works

Comment: Edit: This is happening on iOS only! Android works fine. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

with

```
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

are you using phonegap build?

Comment: Incredible.. This was it... I've tried including cordova.js as well, but left the tags 'type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"'. This is phonegap thing is really getting on my nerves. :(

Comment: Btw: do you know why this is going on?

Comment: I have to figured it out yet but I guess "addEventListener" is Called in cordova.js and NOT in phonegap.js am not sure

Comment: Actually... that wasn't it. :( I think it does not matter what you include cordova.js or phonegap.js (because they are both available, as far as I know). It was an error regarding the localStorage, to be more precise.